# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError after adding [pageSize] attribute to Kendo grid

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui-angular2, pager, page-size

Please find attached code and let me know the possible reason for the error i am getting while running the code in Angular CLI.
This error will gone if i remove the [pageSize]="5" but that will not show default page size in dropdown.
Requirement is like to show second pager on top of Grid

[image]

```html
<kendo-grid #grid class="k-grid-expand-row inner-grid" [kendoGridBinding]="gridData" [height]="530" [pageSize]="5" [skip]="skip" [pageable]="true" [sortable]="true" [filterable]="IsFilterVisible" (pageChange)="onPageChange($event)" [selectable]="{enabled: true, checkboxOnly: true}"
  [loading]="loading" [selectedKeys]="selectedItems" [resizable]="true" [kendoGridSelectBy]="selectionKey" (cellClick)="rowClick($event)">
  <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate position="top">
    <div class="d-flex k-grid-toolbar-content ">
      <div class="pagination-container">
        <p>Show</p>
        <kendo-pager-page-sizes [pageSizes]="[5,10,20,40]"></kendo-pager-page-sizes>
          <kendo-pager-prev-buttons id="ibtPagination Button"></kendo-pager-prev-buttons>
          <kendo-pager-input></kendo-pager-input>
          <kendo-pager-next-buttons id="ibtPagination Button"></kendo-pager-next-buttons>
    </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <kendo-grid>
```

Comment: What is the version of Kendo UI you are using?

Comment: @progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^4.1.1 
this version i am using.

Answer (score 2):

I added the below code in component class.

```
constructor(public cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

And it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

There an [issue with Kendo UI grid](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/2397) with pageSize property. Update the package to 4.1.0 version would fix this.